# improve this array data model

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently making a tiny script that tags cordenades in an array:

```
var paises = ['spain','australia'];
var leftX   = ['270','575'];
var topY    = ['60','220'];
```

When I need to access them:

```
clase = 'spain';
var left_ = leftX[paises.indexOf(clase)];
var top_ = topY[paises.indexOf(clase)];
```

This might be confusing for my workmates to update. How could I make it easier?

Comment: You got three identical answers in about 1 minute. I think your path forward is pretty clear :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var places = {
    "spain":  {
         leftx: '270',
         topY: '60'
    },
    "australia":  {
         leftx: '575',
         topY: '220'
    }
}

//Then:
clase = 'spain';
var left_ = places[clase].leftX;
var top_ = places[clase].topY;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it in an object structure:

```
var paises = {
    spain: { leftX: 270, topY: 60 },
    // etc
}
```

Then it's much easier to access, and you don't have to worry about `.indexOf()` support (this isn't available in older IE versions):

```
clase = 'spain';
var left_ = paises[clase].leftX;
var top_ = paises[clase].topY;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use javascript objects

```
var paises =  { spain: {leftX: 270, topY: 60}, australia: { leftX: 575, topY: 220};

paises.spain.leftX; // 270
// or
paises["spain"].leftX; // 270
// or
paises['spain']['leftX']; // 270
```

So there are many options to access the data, in a conventional JavaScript manor.